# How to properly create and run concurrent tasks using python's asyncio module?

Tags: python, concurrency, task, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I am trying to properly understand and implement two concurrently running [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task) objects using Python 3's relatively new [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module.

In a nutshell, asyncio seems designed to handle asynchronous processes and concurrent `Task` execution over an event loop. It promotes the use of `await` (applied in async functions) as a callback-free way to wait for and use a result, without blocking the event loop. (Futures and callbacks are still a viable alternative.)

It also provides the `asyncio.Task()` class, a specialized subclass of `Future`  designed to wrap coroutines. Preferably invoked by using the `asyncio.ensure_future()` method. The intended use of asyncio tasks is to allow independently running tasks to run 'concurrently' with other tasks within the same event loop. My understanding is that `Tasks` are connected to the event loop which then automatically keeps driving the coroutine between `await` statements.

I like the idea of being able to use concurrent Tasks without needing to use one of the [`Executor`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) classes, but I haven't found much elaboration on implementation.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
import asyncio

print('running async test')

async def say_boo():
    i = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        print('...boo {0}'.format(i))
        i += 1

async def say_baa():
    i = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        print('...baa {0}'.format(i))
        i += 1

# wrap in Task object
# -> automatically attaches to event loop and executes
boo = asyncio.ensure_future(say_boo())
baa = asyncio.ensure_future(say_baa())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

In the case of trying to concurrently run two looping Tasks, I've noticed that unless the Task has an internal `await` expression, it will get stuck in the `while` loop, effectively blocking other tasks from running (much like a normal `while` loop). However, as soon the Tasks have to (a)wait, they seem to run concurrently without an issue.

Thus, the `await` statements seem to provide the event loop with a foothold for switching back and forth between the tasks, giving the effect of concurrency.

Example output with internal `await`:

```
running async test
...boo 0
...baa 0
...boo 1
...baa 1
...boo 2
...baa 2
```

Example output *without* internal `await`:

```
...boo 0
...boo 1
...boo 2
...boo 3
...boo 4
```

### Questions

Does this implementation pass for a 'proper' example of concurrent looping Tasks in `asyncio`?

Is it correct that the only way this works is for a `Task` to provide a blocking point (`await` expression) in order for the event loop to juggle multiple tasks?

### Edit

2022 UPDATE: Please note that the `asyncio` API has changed fairly substantially since this question was asked. See the newly marked as correct answer which now shows the correct use of the API given Python 3.10. I still recommend the answer from @dano for broader knowledge of how this works under the hood.

Comment: Yes, task atomically executes itself from `yield from` to next `yield from`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The functions [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) and [`asyncio.get_event_loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) are deprecated in Python 3.10.

You can run the two coroutines `say_boo` and `say_baa` concurrently through [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task):

```py
async def main():
    boo = asyncio.create_task(say_boo())
    baa = asyncio.create_task(say_baa())
    await boo
    await baa

asyncio.run(main())
```

You can also use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)

```py
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(say_boo(), say_baa())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: For the benefit of new views of this question I am marking this question as correct given the more recent changes to the API.

Answer (score 103):

Yes, any coroutine that's running inside your event loop will block other coroutines and tasks from running, unless it

1. Calls another coroutine using `yield from` or `await` (if using Python 3.5+).
2. Returns.

This is because `asyncio` is single-threaded; the only way for the event loop to run is for no other coroutine to be actively executing. Using `yield from`/`await` suspends the coroutine temporarily, giving the event loop a chance to work.

Your example code is fine, but in many cases, you probably wouldn't want long-running code that isn't doing asynchronous I/O running inside the event loop to begin with. In those cases, it often makes more sense to use [`asyncio.loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to run the code in a background thread or process. `ProcessPoolExecutor` would be the better choice if your task is CPU-bound, `ThreadPoolExecutor` would be used if you need to do some I/O that isn't `asyncio`-friendly.

Your two loops, for example, are completely CPU-bound and don't share any state, so the best performance would come from using `ProcessPoolExecutor` to run each loop in parallel across CPUs:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

print('running async test')

def say_boo():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print('...boo {0}'.format(i))
        i += 1


def say_baa():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print('...baa {0}'.format(i))
        i += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    boo = loop.run_in_executor(executor, say_boo)
    baa = loop.run_in_executor(executor, say_baa)

    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Thanks. Great timing as I was just wondering about this very topic re: using executors.

Comment: Trying the above code and am finding that the boo Task is blocking baa from running unless I add the yield from asyncio.sleep(0) into each of the while True loops?

Comment: Also re-worked the run_in_executor bits as follows: loop.run_in_executor(executor, asyncio.Task(say_boo()))

Comment: @shongololo Sorry, fixed. `asyncio.async` should be used, instead of the `asyncio.Task` constructor directly. We don't want `say_boo` and `say_baa` to be coroutines, they should just be ordinary functions that run outside of the event loop, so you shouldn't add `yield from` calls to them or wrap them in an `asyncio.Task`.

Comment: How can I add a callback when the task being run in the executor finishes?

Comment: Looks like [asyncio.async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async) is an alias to [ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) and is now deprecated

Comment: @ScottRobinson I've updated my answer to use `ensure_future` now that `async` is deprecated.

Comment: I've been wondering how to code up a single-core network daemon that's very async with several cores worth of cpu-burning tasks, and this answer is a roadmap that makes it easy. The Python docs don't explain this stuff very well at all. Thanks!

Comment: How would I run two different coroutines using multiple threads?  I can find examples like this one, which illustrate how to run a regular function in multiple threads, but I can't find an example the other way around.

Comment: @MikeyE That's because normally there's no reason to use multiple thread to run coroutines - they're designed to run concurrently in a single thread. To do what you're asking for, you'd need to start two separate asyncio event loops, each in their own thread, and run a coroutine on each. But you should make sure you actually need to do that, since it would be an unusual requirement.

Comment: I copied the code and ran it using Python 3.9. It throws an error - RuntimeError: no running event loop; but continues execution. 
Furthermore, as mentioned above, boo is blocking further code execution. 

I think I get the idea - create tasks, which will be spawned in current loop, but executed on 'external' executor - voila, working in background. But it doesn't work. First task is being ran immediately and blocks the rest since it is on the same loop.

I deleted asyncio.create_task() and it seems to work correctly - both functions start to run on the loop.run_forever() line.

Comment: @bezimienny thanks for pointing that out. When I initially wrote this answer, `asyncio.async(` worked fine, and it also still worked when I that was deprecated and I switched it to `asyncio.ensure_future`. However, you are correct that it does not work when using `asyncio.create_task`. The asyncio docs describe `create_task` as a replacement for `ensure_future`, but the semantics aren't exactly the same, as it turns out. As you suggested, I just removed the `create_task` call altogether.

Answer (score 16):

You don't necessarily need a `yield from x` to give control over to the event loop.

In your example, I think the *proper* way would be to do a `yield None` or equivalently a simple `yield`, rather than a `yield from asyncio.sleep(0.001)`:

```py
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def say_boo():
  i = 0
  while True:
    yield None
    print("...boo {0}".format(i))
    i += 1

@asyncio.coroutine
def say_baa():
  i = 0
  while True:
    yield
    print("...baa {0}".format(i))
    i += 1

boo_task = asyncio.async(say_boo())
baa_task = asyncio.async(say_baa())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

Coroutines are just plain old Python generators.
Internally, the `asyncio` event loop keeps a record of these generators and calls `gen.send()` on each of them one by one in a never ending loop. Whenever you `yield`, the call to `gen.send()` completes and the loop can move on. (I'm simplifying it; take a look around https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#l265 for the actual code)

That said, I would still go the `run_in_executor` route if you need to do CPU intensive computation without sharing data.

Comment: Works in Python 3.4 but doesn't seem to work in Python 3.5. Is there a similar approach for 3.5? (`None` seems to be more elegant than using `asyncio.sleep()` everywhere...)

Comment: Since Python 3.5, the *right* way to do this is with a `asyncio.sleep(0)`. [See this discussion.](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284)