# I want to run a function every x sec in one thread python

Tags: python

I want to run a function every x sec and never end unless interrupted. Using threading.Timer will spawn a new thread everytime. Is there a way to achieve the same in one thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import time

def job():
    ... code for the function you want to run

def execute():
    while(True):
        job()
        time.sleep(x) # where x is the interval between jobs in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called asyncio in Python 3.4+ which will allow you to do a repeated task every so often plus do your regular stuff.  You put all your tasks on a loop that runs forever.

[How can I periodically execute a function with asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512182/how-can-i-periodically-execute-a-function-with-asyncio) has an answer using this library.