# Asyncio, await and infinite loops

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop, python-asyncio, discord.py

```
async def start(channel):
    while True:
        m = await client.send_message(channel, "Generating... ")
        generator.makeFile()
        with open('tmp.png', 'rb') as f:
            await client.send_file(channel, f) 
        await client.delete_message(m)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

I have a discord bot that runs a task every 2 seconds. I tried using an infinite loop for this, but the script crashes with a `Task was destroyed but it is still pending!` I have read about asyncio's coroutines, but none of the examples that I found use `await` in them. Is it possible avoid this error, by running a coroutine with `await`, for example?

Comment: `await` is not a problem here. More the `while True` is also common way for periodic calls (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512182/how-can-i-periodically-execute-a-function-with-asyncio). Show how you execute that function, are you tried to stop the task in the code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Task was destroyed but it is still pending!` is warning that you receive when you call `loop.close()` when some of [tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) in your script aren't finished. Usually you should avoid this situation because unfinished task may not release some resources. You need either to await task done or [cancel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) it before event loop closed.

Since you have infinite loop you probably would need to cancel task, example:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress


async def start():
    # your infinite loop here, for example:
    while True:
        print('echo')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    task = asyncio.Task(start())

    # let script some thime to work:
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    # cancel task to avoid warning:
    task.cancel()
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task  # await for task cancellation


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207) for more information about tasks.

Comment: If i'm awaiting two async tasks(task1 and task2) inside main func in the same order, task1 is having a while true loop and calling one more async task(task3) inside that while loop. Will the execution be ever passed to task2 in this case?

Comment: @y_159 sorry, it's hard for me to follow. Any chance you could write this in code?

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov thanks, I tested via a script and async is working as it is supposed to even if tasks contain while True loops.