# Asyncio - run tasks cyclically and politely stop them with ctrl+C

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am writing a pyModbus server with asyncio, based on [this example](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples.html#updating-server-example).
Alongside the server I've got a serial device which I'm communicating with and a server updating task.
One task should check the status of the serial device every 500ms.
The server updating task should check if there are any changes in the status of the serial device and update the info on the server. Moreover, if there is a request waiting on the server it should call another task which will send necessary info to the serial device.

My three questions are:

1. How should I stop the server politely? For now the app is running only in console so it is stopped by ctrl+c - how can I stop the server without causing an avalanche of errors?
2. How can I implement tasks to be executed cyclically (let's say I want to frefresh the server data every 500ms)? I've found the `aiocron` module but as far as I can tell its functionalities are a bit limtied as it is intended just for calling functions in intervals.
3. How can I politely cancel all the tasks before stopping the server (the infinitely, cyclically running ones) when closing the app?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Speaking of running cyclical tasks and cancelling them - is this a proper way to do that? This doesn't rise any errors but does it clean eveything correctly? (I created this sketch compiling a dozen of questions on stackoverflow, I am not sure if this makes sense)

```
import asyncio

async def periodic():
    try:
        while True:
            print('periodic')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as ex:
        print('task1', type(ex))
        raise

async def periodic2():
    try:
        while True:
            print('periodic2')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as ex:
        print('task2', type(ex))
        raise


async def main():
            tasks = []
            task = asyncio.create_task(periodic())
            tasks.append(task)
            task2 = asyncio.create_task(periodic2())
            tasks.append(task2)
            for task in tasks:
                await task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

> FYI: I'm writing down the answers to your questions one by one so that anyone that arrives on this Question understands how you ended up on some pieces of your EDIT and to also add the answer on how to cancel the tasks without breaking something.

1. Gracefully Stopping the Server:

You can handle the graceful shutdown of your asyncio application by catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` signal (triggered by Ctrl+C) and then cancelling your running tasks and closing your resources. Here's an example of how to do this:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    # Your other tasks and setup here

try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Received Ctrl+C. Stopping gracefully...")
    # Cancel all running tasks
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()
    # Optionally: Close any open resources (sockets, files, etc.)
    # Cleanup code here
finally:
    loop.close()
```

2. Implementing Tasks to Run Cyclically:

To run tasks cyclically with asyncio, you can use the asyncio.sleep function within your tasks. Here's a basic example:

```py
import asyncio

async def task_to_run():
    while True:
        # Your cyclic task code here
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)  # Sleep for 500ms (0.5 seconds)

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(task_to_run())
    # Your other tasks and setup here
```

This code will execute `task_to_run` every 500ms. You can adjust the sleep duration according to your needs.

3. Politely Canceling All Running Tasks:

As shown in the code example for gracefully stopping the server (in the Ctrl+C handling part), you can use `task.cancel()` to politely cancel all running tasks before stopping the server. This ensures that any ongoing tasks are given the opportunity to clean up before they exit. [This is done by raising the `asyncio.CancelledError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-cancellation) as you have used on your EDIT. Remember to handle these exceptions or any Exception properly in your tasks to avoid unhandled exceptions causing your program to terminate abruptly.