# Using asyncio to run a function at the start (00 seconds) of every minute

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run several functions at the same time (approximately or course) with different parameters and repeat that at the start of every minute.

I managed to get an `asyncio` example to run where I get a function `callback` to run at specific times with a different parameter, but what I can't figure out is how to run it (and keep running it forever) at very specific times (i.e. I want to run it at the start of every minute, so at 19:00:00, 19:01:00, etc..).

Asyncio `call_at` should be able to do that, but it uses a time format that is not the standard python time format and I can't figure out to specify that time format as the 00 seconds of the next minute.

```
import asyncio
import time


def callback(n, loop, msg):
    print(msg)
    print('callback {} invoked at {}'.format(n, loop.time()))


async def main(loop):
    now = loop.time()
    print('clock time: {}'.format(time.time()))
    print('loop  time: {}'.format(now))

    print('registering callbacks')
    loop.call_at(now + 0.2, callback, 1, loop, 'a')
    loop.call_at(now + 0.1, callback, 2, loop, 'b')
    loop.call_soon(callback, 3, loop, 'c')

    await asyncio.sleep(1)


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    print('entering event loop')
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main(event_loop))
finally:
    print('closing event loop')
    event_loop.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like some commentators stated, there is no easy a resilient way to do this in pure Python with only asyncIO, but with the **apscheduler** library it becomes actually quite easy.

```py
import asyncio
import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler


def tick():
    print("Tick! The time is: %s" % datetime.datetime.now())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, "cron", minute="*")
    scheduler.start()
    print("Press Ctrl+{0} to exit".format("Break" if os.name == "nt" else "C"))

    # Execution will block here until Ctrl+C (Ctrl+Break on Windows) is pressed.
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Comment: Would it be possible to tick the time every 30 seconds? like: `00:00 , 00:30` ...

Answer (score 8):

As others have noted, there is no built-in functionality for that kind of thing, you will need to write it yourself. It is straightforward to implement, though - a simple version could look like this:

```
import asyncio, datetime

async def at_minute_start(cb):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        after_minute = now.second + now.microsecond / 1_000_000
        if after_minute:
            await asyncio.sleep(60 - after_minute)
        cb()
```

This doesn't use `call_later`, it is a coroutine which can be canceled when no longer necessary. It simply takes the seconds value of the current wallclock time `x`, and sleeps `(60 - x)` to reach the next minute. Here is a test:

```
import time
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(at_minute_start(lambda: print(time.asctime())))
loop.run_forever()

# output:
Wed Feb 28 21:36:00 2018
Wed Feb 28 21:37:00 2018
Wed Feb 28 21:38:00 2018
...
```

Unfortunately, the simple implementation can misbehave if `asyncio.sleep` ever happens to sleep a tiny bit *shorter* than the requested period, e.g. due to clock skew. In that case the subsequent `asyncio.sleep` will try to again reach the start of the same minute and sleep for only a fraction of a second, resulting in the callback effectively firing twice in quick succession. To prevent that, additional code is needed to compensate for the short sleeps:

```
async def at_minute_start(cb):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    wait_for_next_minute = False
    while True:
        after_minute = now.second + now.microsecond / 1_000_000
        if after_minute != 0:
            to_next_minute = 60 - after_minute
        else:
            to_next_minute = 0  # already at the minute start
        if wait_for_next_minute:
            to_next_minute += 60
        await asyncio.sleep(to_next_minute)
        cb()
        prev = now
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        # if we're still at the same minute, our sleep was slightly
        # too short, so we'll need to wait an additional minute
        wait_for_next_minute = now.minute == prev.minute
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple way to do this. You can't rely on `loop.time()` as "real-world" clock.

Only way around is to count the timedelta with `datetime`/`time` modules and call `loop.call_later` with calculated delay. And yes, its super-cumbersome.

Take a look at this question for examples: [How can I periodically execute a function with asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512182/how-can-i-periodically-execute-a-function-with-asyncio)

Comment: Yes, I have found a nice library that makes the all process quite straightforward though, **apscheduler**, I'll post an answer with it.