# Python: Execute code when the next minute starts

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am exploring automation in my program, and I need it to run code every time the next minute starts, an example:

Let's say it is 8:12:32,
I would want it to run at 8:13:00 instead of 8:13:32

Because of this, sleep doesn't work for my purposes.

I was searching around Stack Overflow for an answer before I opened a question and I found something like this:

```
def minute_passed(oldepoch):
    return time.time() - oldepoch >= 60
```

However, it has to be manually called every time I want to check. I need it to continuously test.

Sorry, Python is kind of a new experience for me.

Currently using Python 3.6 and Windows

Comment: Use a cronjob or sleep(60). Sorry, on mobile!

Comment: Ah saw sleep note. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows, sorry I should have put that in the post

Comment: @AndrewChon You can use [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49053648/3091398).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From a comment by Codelt*

You can use [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49053648/3091398)

Answer (score 1):

If you know time in seconds, then you can try

```
sleep(60 - seconds)
```