# Alternative to asyncio.gather which I can keep adding coroutines to at runtime?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I need to be able to keep adding coroutines to the asyncio loop at runtime. I tried using `create_task()` thinking that this would do what I want, but it still needs to be awaited.

This is the code I had, not sure if there is a simple edit to make it work?

```
async def get_value_from_api():
    global ASYNC_CLIENT
    return ASYNC_CLIENT.get(api_address)


async def print_subs():
    count = await get_value_from_api()
    print(count)


async def save_subs_loop():
    while True:
        asyncio.create_task(print_subs())
        time.sleep(0.1)


async def start():
    global ASYNC_CLIENT
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as ASYNC_CLIENT:
        await save_subs_loop()


asyncio.run(start())
```

Comment: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await) and I think it might be useful, but I'm unsure if it's a duplicate. Could  you check it out and see if it helps you?

Comment: Another similar approach can be inspired from this answer for periodic addition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512182/how-can-i-periodically-execute-a-function-with-asyncio?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: So you want to gather results from a dynamic queue e.g. `async for done in consume(queue): queue.extend(do_something(done))`

Comment: How do you know that there is no more work, and the `async for` should stop?

Comment: That is a classic producer-consumer pattern.

Comment: @MarcSances Thanks, but it looks like that answer is suggesting the way I have done it, or by using `ensure_future()` instead of `create_task()`, but I have tried both and nothing happens unless await it, in which case it's not asynchronous. I don't really understand why it's not working

Comment: @JishanShaikh I think that answer is actually synchronous, because an `await` in the while loop will be blocking the loop, meaning that each `asyncio.sleep` gets called sequentially. What I need is something which doesn't need to finish before the next task is created.

Answer (score 3):

`asyncio.create_task()` works as you describe it. The problem you are having here is that you create an infinite loop here:

```py
async def save_subs_loop():
    while True:
        asyncio.create_task(print_subs())
        time.sleep(0.1) # do not use time.sleep() in async code EVER
```

`save_subs_loop()` keeps creating tasks but control is never yielded back to the event loop, because there is no `await` in there. Try

```py
async def save_subs_loop():
    while True:
        asyncio.create_task(print_subs())
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # yield control back to loop to give tasks a chance to actually run
```

This problem is so common I'm thinking python should raise a `RuntimeError` if it detects `time.sleep()` within a coroutine :-)

Comment: Ah yes this was the problem...now my code works as I want...thanks

Answer (score 2):

I once created [similar pattern](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/PersonalToolkit/blob/581ff9540b46228269a0e8405ef49c8fc8f3ed4b/DynamicTaskViewerDemo/MainUI.py#L164-L187) when I was mixing `trio` and `kivy`, which was demonstration of running multiple coroutines asynchronously.

It use a `trio.MemoryChannel` which is roughly equivalent to `asyncio.Queue`, I'll just refer it as `queue` here.

Main idea is:

1. Wrap each task with class, which has run function.
2. Make class object's own async method to put object itself into `queue` when execution is done.
3. Create a global task-spawning loop to wait for the object in `queue` and schedule execution/create task for the object.

```py
import asyncio
import traceback

import httpx


async def task_1(client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    resp = await client.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
    print(resp.read())
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # without this would be IP ban


async def task_2(client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    resp = await client.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/meow/")
    print(resp.read())
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


class CoroutineWrapper:
    def __init__(self, queue: asyncio.Queue,  coro_func, *param):
        self.func = coro_func
        self.param = param
        self.queue = queue

    async def run(self):
        try:
            await self.func(*self.param)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return
        
        # put itself back into queue
        await self.queue.put(self)


class KeepRunning:
    def __init__(self):
        # queue for gathering CoroutineWrapper
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()

    def add_task(self, coro, *param):
        wrapped = CoroutineWrapper(self.queue, coro, *param)
        
        # add tasks to be executed in queue
        self.queue.put_nowait(wrapped)

    async def task_processor(self):
        task: CoroutineWrapper
        while task := await self.queue.get():
            # wait for new CoroutineWrapper Object then schedule it's async method execution
            asyncio.create_task(task.run())


async def main():
    keep_running = KeepRunning()
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        keep_running.add_task(task_1, client)
        keep_running.add_task(task_2, client)

        await keep_running.task_processor()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Server

```
import time

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return str(time.time())


@app.route("/meow/")
def meow():
    return "meow"


app.run()
```

Output:

```
b'meow'
b'1639920445.965701'
b'1639920446.0767004'
b'1639920446.1887035'
b'1639920446.2986999'
b'1639920446.4067013'
b'meow'
b'1639920446.516704'
b'1639920446.6267014'
...
```

You can see tasks running repeatedly on their own pace.

---

### Old answer

Seems like you only want to cycle fixed amount of tasks.

In that case just iterate list of coroutine with `itertools.cycle`

But this is no different with synchronous, so lemme know if you need is asynchronous.

```py
import asyncio
import itertools

import httpx


async def main_task(client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    resp = await client.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
    print(resp.read())
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # without this would be IP ban


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        for coroutine in itertools.cycle([main_task]):
            await coroutine(client)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Server:

```py
import time

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return str(time.time())


app.run()
```

Output:

```
b'1639918937.7694323'
b'1639918937.8804302'
b'1639918937.9914327'
b'1639918938.1014295'
b'1639918938.2124324'
b'1639918938.3204308'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [TaskThread](https://elsampsa.github.io/task_thread/_build/html/index.html) framework

- It allows you to add tasks in runtime
- Tasks are re-scheduled periodically (like in your while loop up there)
- There is a consumer / producer framework built in (parent/child relationships) which you seem to need

disclaimer: I wrote TaskThread out of necessity & it's been a life saver.