# How to periodically execute coroutines in asyncio when then are potentially longer than the period interval

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

I want to execute functions at specific time intervals. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204092/4810108), I am able to do so using `asyncio`, but only when the time the functions take is less than the interval. For example, when the function time (wait) is less than interval time:

```
wait = 2
interval = 4

async def function1(wait):
    await aio.sleep(wait)
    t = round(time.time() - start_time, 1)
    print("time function1 executed:", t)

async def function2():
    t = round(time.time() - start_time, 1)
    print("time function2 executed:", t)

async def scheduler(interval):
    while True:
        t = round(time.time() - start_time, 1)
        print("time functions were scheduled:", t)
        await aio.gather(
                         aio.sleep(interval - (time.time() - start_time) % interval),
                         function1(wait),
                         function2()
                         )

start_time = time.time()
aio.run(scheduler(interval))
```

I get expected behaviour where functions run at my specified interval (4sec):

```
time functions were scheduled: 0.0
time function2 executed: 0.0
time function1 executed: 2.0
time functions were scheduled: 4.0
time function2 executed: 4.0
time function1 executed: 6.0
time functions were scheduled: 8.0
time function2 executed: 8.0
time function1 executed: 10.0
time functions were scheduled: 12.0
time function2 executed: 12.0
time function1 executed: 14.0
```

But when wait > interval:

```
wait = 5
interval = 4
```

I get:

```
time functions were scheduled: 0.0
time function2 executed: 0.0
time function1 executed: 5.0
time functions were scheduled: 5.0
time function2 executed: 5.0
time function1 executed: 10.0
time functions were scheduled: 10.0
time function2 executed: 10.0
time function1 executed: 15.0
time functions were scheduled: 15.0
time function2 executed: 15.0
time function1 executed: 20.1
```

I am completely new to asyncio and have tried playing around with `asyncio.wait_for()` (using only a single coroutine function) and `asyncio.wait()` (for multiple coroutine functions) but I keep getting strange behaviours where the scheduling seems to work, but every so often a load of output from the functions is dumped out... I think it may have something to do with cancelling the over-running functions but I don't understand how to cancel them when the interval is up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am on a Windows machine, and use `import nest_asyncio; nest_asyncio.apply()` to solve conflicts from using asyncio in spyder IDE.