# asyncio matplotlib show() still freezes program

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-asyncio

I wish to **run a simulation** while at the **same time output its progress in a plot**. I've been looking through a lot of examples of threading and multiprocessing, but they are all pretty complex. So I thought with Python's new `asyncio` library this should be easier.

I found an example ([How to use 'yield' inside async function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549846/how-to-use-yield-inside-async-function)) and modified it for my cause:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import asyncio
import numpy as np


class DataAnalysis():
    def __init__(self):
        # asyncio so we can plot data and run simulation in parallel
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(self.plot_reward())
        finally:
            loop.run_until_complete(
                loop.shutdown_asyncgens())  # see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.shutdown_asyncgens
            loop.close()

    async def async_generator(self):
        for i in range(3):
            await asyncio.sleep(.4)
            yield i * i

    async def plot_reward(self):
        # Prepare the data
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

        # Plot the data
        plt.plot(x, x, label='linear')

        #plt.show()

        # add lines to plot
        async for i in self.async_generator():
            print(i)
            # Show the plot
            plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DataAnalysis()
```

### Question

I added a simple `plt.show()` and the program still freezes. I thought with `asyncio` I could run it in parallel? Obviously my knowledge is still lacking.
An example that does the following would be really helpful:

- Add a line to a plot (of `matplotlib`) everytime `async_generator` returns a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I misunderstood asyncio, it doesn't make run things in parallel ([use asyncio for parallel tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558484/use-asyncio-for-parallel-tasks)).

It seems the only thing that worked for me was `plt.pause(0.001)` ([Plotting in a non-blocking way with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269157/plotting-in-a-non-blocking-way-with-matplotlib)). `plt.draw()` opened a window, but it didn't show anything and `plt.show` freezes the program. It seems that `plt.show(block=False)` is deprecated and using `plt.ion` gives the problem that the final result closes when the program is finished. Also `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` didn't make the plot draw a line.

### Working code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import asyncio
import matplotlib.cbook
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=matplotlib.cbook.mplDeprecation)


class DataAnalysis():
    def __init__(self):
        # asyncio so we can plot data and run simulation in parallel
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(self.plot_reward())
        finally:
            loop.run_until_complete(
                loop.shutdown_asyncgens())  # see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.shutdown_asyncgens
            loop.close()
            # keep plot window open
            plt.show()

    async def async_generator(self):
        for i in range(3):
            await asyncio.sleep(.4)
            yield i * i

    async def plot_reward(self):
        #plt.ion()  # enable interactive mode

        # receive dicts with training results
        async for i in self.async_generator():
            print(i)
            # update plot
            if i == 0:
                plt.plot([2, 3, 4])
            elif i == 1:
                plt.plot([3, 4, 5])

            #plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.1)
            #await asyncio.sleep(0.4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    da = DataAnalysis()
```

### Notes

- You get however a deprecated message: `python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2445: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented
  warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)`, which you can suppress with: `warnings.filterwarnings()`.
- I'm not sure if `asyncio` was actually necessary for my use case...
- Difference between `threading` and `multiprocessing` for who's interested: [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)