# Run two async functions without blocking each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have an async function and I want to run another one "in parallel". But I need to do it at a certain moment **inside that first function**.

I've seen a lot of examples, but all of them were launching two functions at the same time, and that's not what I want.

I've created this simple example to illustrate what I want to achieve (and what I've tried):

```
import asyncio
import time

async def print_letters():
    for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
        print(letter)
        time.sleep(1)

async def print_numbers(loop):
    for number in range(1, 7):
        if(number == 3):
            # same result with create_task
            # loop.create_task(print_letters())
            asyncio.ensure_future(print_letters())
        print(number)
        time.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(print_numbers(loop))
print('End')
```

The current output:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, A, B, C, D, End

The desired output would be something like this:

> 1, 2, 3, A, 4, B, 5, C, 6 D, End

I've tried some other stuff (`asyncio.wait`, for example) but none worked as expected. Also the documentation it's not easy to understand when you're pretty new with Python `asyncio`.

If the question is unclear or there's something missing, let me know so I can edit it. I appreciate any kind of help.

**Python 3.6.2**

Comment: it doesn't run 2 methods in parallel. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40559338/5648253

Comment: @Helpinghand You're right! I expressed it wrong. What I wanted is to behave like it was running in parallel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need your asynchronous functions to yield the CPU while waiting, so that other asynchronous functions get a chance to run. Yielding the CPU is done, using the `await` keyword. In addition you need to use the `sleep(...)` funtion defined in `asyncio` as the normal `time.sleep(...)` does not allow re-entry into the yielded funtion. All-in-all, this requires your program to be

```
import asyncio

async def print_letters():
    for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
        print(letter)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def print_numbers(loop):
    for number in range(1, 7):
        if(number == 3):
            # same result with create_task
            # loop.create_task(print_letters())
            asyncio.ensure_future(print_letters())
        print(number)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(print_numbers(loop))
print('End')
```

Thus, all you practically have to do, is replace `time.sleep(...)` with `await asyncio.sleep(...)`.