# How to create better coroutines in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

I want to create two asynchronic functions, and I don't know when I will need to run any of them, but they have to not interrupt each other

```
import asyncio


async def func1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("func1 completed")


async def func2():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("func2 completed")


asyncio.run(func1())

asyncio.run(func2())
```

When I run it, the second "asyncio.run()" will wait till the first one completes, and only then, it runs the func2 with 1 second delay:

```
func1 completed
*1 second delay*
func2 completed
```

But I want to run them at the same time, so they result will look like this:

```
func1 completed
*no delay*
func2 completed
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269370/how-to-properly-create-and-run-concurrent-tasks-using-pythons-asyncio-module

Comment: Why are you using coroutines when you don’t actually (seem to know how to) run more than one at once? Coroutines are useful only when running at least dozens, ideally hundreds or even thousands of coroutines at once. Are you sure you are aware of the tradeoffs and *need* coroutines and not, say, just threads?

Comment: The accepted answer here is what you are after : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73603213/218663

Comment: While the motivation for this question is not provided, I think this is a nice example of a minimal reproducible example, stripped of any irrelevant details, going straight to the point with code we can cut and paste. +1

Comment: @joanis The motivation would be useful  to gauge whether starting separate event loops actually serves a purpose. This could be intentional to interleave sync and async sections of a program, or it could just be in error for lack of knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you want to use `asyncio.gather`.
Take a look [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-asyncio-gather/), it has an example with two calls :)

Answer (score -1):

I just discovered threads from threading, now I can run functions whenever I want, without waiting for running ones to complete.

```
import threading
import time


def func1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("func1 completed")


def func2():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("func2 completed")


threading.Thread(target=func1).start()
# no delay
threading.Thread(target=func2).start()
```

They will print "completed" at the same time.